# PowerBI Matrix total and percentage issue

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

In Power BI, I want create a Matrix Table, which will be showing both Fund Total and Percentage of Funds.

Matrix automatically creating the fund total and grand total for me. But How can I add the percentage of funds with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to just include the value once again and this time round select % of grand total as your representation.
[image]